# How to capitalize the first letter of each word in a string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

What’s the best way to capitalize the first letter of each word in a string in SQL Server.

Comment: Does this have to be done in SQL Server? It's not something I would associate with a database server, but something done by form validation or even a view.

Comment: PostgreSQL users: UPDATE [table] SET your_col = initcap(lower(your_col )); This is not a Postgre question, but it appears first in google regardless.

Answer (score 92, accepted):

From http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/initcap.aspx

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[InitCap] ( @InputString varchar(4000) ) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Index          INT
DECLARE @Char           CHAR(1)
DECLARE @PrevChar       CHAR(1)
DECLARE @OutputString   VARCHAR(255)

SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString)
SET @Index = 1

WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
BEGIN
    SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
    SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                         ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
                    END

    IF @PrevChar IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', '(')
    BEGIN
        IF @PrevChar != '''' OR UPPER(@Char) != 'S'
            SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, @Index, 1, UPPER(@Char))
    END

    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END

RETURN @OutputString

END
GO
```

There is a simpler/smaller one here (but doesn't work if any row doesn't have spaces, "Invalid length parameter passed to the RIGHT function."):

http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/17608

Comment: what is meaning of UPPER(@Char) != 'S'? why we are using this?

Comment: The comparison to 'S' is to make sure that the S is not capitalized when writing words like `that's`

Comment: Function is as bit slow but it is working correctly. How can I improve performance?

Comment: Doesn't work for words that have an `'` that aren't followed by an `S`. Such as `I'm`, `you've`, etc.

Comment: Why OutputString is 255 when input is 4000 and returns too?

Answer (score 5):

As a table-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.InitCap(@v AS VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
WITH a AS (
    SELECT (
        SELECT UPPER(LEFT(value, 1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(value, 2, LEN(value))) AS 'data()'
        FROM string_split(@v, ' ')
        ORDER BY CHARINDEX(value,@v)
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE) ret)

SELECT CAST(a.ret AS varchar(MAX)) ret from a
GO
```

Note that `string_split` requires `COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL` 130.

Comment: Please be aware of non-guaranteed order of STRING_SPLIT function. I'd add ORDER BY CHARINDEX(value,@v) after FROM line

Answer (score 3):

The suggested function works fine, however, if you do not want to create any function this is how I do it:

```
select ID,Name
,string_agg(concat(upper(substring(value,1,1)),lower(substring(value,2,len(value)-1))),' ') as ModifiedName 
from Table_Customer 
cross apply String_Split(replace(trim(Name),'  ',' '),' ')
where Name is not null
group by ID,Name;
```

The above query split the words by space (' ') and create different rows of each having one substring, then convert the first letter of each substring to upper and keep remaining as lower. The final step is to string aggregate based on the key.

Answer (score 2):

A variation of the one I've been using for quite some time is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [widget].[properCase](@string varchar(8000)) RETURNS varchar(8000) AS
BEGIN   
    SET @string = LOWER(@string)
    DECLARE @i INT
    SET @i = ASCII('a')
    WHILE @i <= ASCII('z')
    BEGIN
        SET @string = REPLACE( @string, ' ' + CHAR(@i), ' ' + CHAR(@i-32))
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END
    SET @string = CHAR(ASCII(LEFT(@string, 1))-32) + RIGHT(@string, LEN(@string)-1)
    RETURN @string
END
```

You can easily modify to handle characters after items other than spaces if you wanted to.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution without using the loop - pure set-based approach with recursive CTE

```
create function [dbo].InitCap (@value varchar(max))
returns varchar(max) as
begin

    declare
        @separator char(1) = ' ',
        @result varchar(max) = '';

    with r as (
        select value, cast(null as varchar(max)) [x], cast('' as varchar(max)) [char], 0 [no] from (select rtrim(cast(@value as varchar(max))) [value]) as j
        union all
        select right(value, len(value)-case charindex(@separator, value) when 0 then len(value) else charindex(@separator, value) end) [value]
        , left(r.[value], case charindex(@separator, r.value) when 0 then len(r.value) else abs(charindex(@separator, r.[value])-1) end ) [x]
        , left(r.[value], 1)
        , [no] + 1 [no]
        from r where value > '')

    select @result = @result +
    case
        when ascii([char]) between 97 and 122 
            then stuff(x, 1, 1, char(ascii([char])-32))
        else x
    end + @separator
    from r where x is not null;

    set @result = rtrim(@result);

    return @result;
end
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the answer to the same question in Oracle/PLSQL then you may use the function INITCAP. Below is an example for the attribute **dname** from a table **department** which has the values ('sales', 'management', 'production', 'development').

```
SQL> select INITCAP(dname) from department;

INITCAP(DNAME)
--------------------------------------------------
Sales
Management
Production
Development
```

Comment: This question is for SQL Server and T-SQL, not Oracle or PLSQL.

Answer (score 2):

```
;WITH StudentList(Name) AS (
      SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50), 'Carl-VAN')
UNION SELECT 'Dean o''brian'
UNION SELECT 'Andrew-le-Smith'
UNION SELECT 'Eddy thompson'
UNION SELECT 'BOBs-your-Uncle'
), Student AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50), UPPER(LEFT(Name, 1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(Name, 2, LEN(Name)))) Name, 
           pos = PATINDEX('%[-'' ]%', Name)
    FROM StudentList
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50), LEFT(Name, pos) + UPPER(SUBSTRING(Name, pos + 1, 1)) + SUBSTRING(Name, pos + 2, LEN(Name))) Name, 
           pos = CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[-'' ]%', RIGHT(Name, LEN(Name) - pos)) = 0 THEN 0 ELSE pos + PATINDEX('%[-'' ]%', RIGHT(Name, LEN(Name) - pos)) END
    FROM Student
    WHERE pos > 0
)
SELECT Name
FROM Student 
WHERE pos = 0
ORDER BY Name
```

This will result in:

- Andrew-Le-Smith
- Bobs-Your-Uncle
- Carl-Van
- Dean O'Brian
- Eddy Thompson

Using a recursive CTE set based query should out perform a procedural while loop query.
Here I also have made my separate to be 3 different characters [-' ] instead of 1 for a more advanced example. Using PATINDEX as I have done allows me to look for many characters. You could also use CHARINDEX on a single character and this function excepts a third parameter StartFromPosition so I could further simply my 2nd part of the recursion of the pos formula to (assuming a space): pos = CHARINDEX(' ', Name, pos + 1).

Answer (score 1):

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @string varchar(100) = 'asdsadsd asdad asd'
DECLARE @ResultString varchar(200) = ''
DECLARE @index int = 1
DECLARE @flag bit = 0
DECLARE @temp varchar(2) = ''
WHILE (@Index <LEN(@string)+1)
    BEGIN
        SET @temp = SUBSTRING(@string, @Index-1, 1)
        --select @temp
        IF @temp = ' ' OR @index = 1
            BEGIN
                SET @ResultString = @ResultString + UPPER(SUBSTRING(@string, @Index, 1))
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                
                SET @ResultString = @ResultString + LOWER(SUBSTRING(@string, @Index, 1)) 
            END 

        SET @Index = @Index+ 1--increase the index
    END
SELECT @ResultString
END
```

Answer (score 1):

fname is column name if fname value is akhil then UPPER(left(fname,1)) provide capital First letter(A) and substring function  SUBSTRING(fname,2,LEN(fname)) provide(khil) concate both using + then result is (Akhil)

```
select UPPER(left(fname,1))+SUBSTRING(fname,2,LEN(fname)) as fname
FROM [dbo].[akhil]
```

Comment: Give some explanation so that it would be easy to understand the solution

Comment: hi @Harsha B, I explained it if any query comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Capitalize](@text NVARCHAR(MAX)) RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX) AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';
    DECLARE @c NVARCHAR(1);
    DECLARE @i INT = 1;
    DECLARE @isPrevSpace BIT = 1;

    WHILE @i <= LEN(@text)
    BEGIN
        SET @c = SUBSTRING(@text, @i, 1);
        SET @result += IIF(@isPrevSpace = 1, UPPER(@c), LOWER(@c));
        SET @isPrevSpace = IIF(@c LIKE '[    -]', 1, 0);
        SET @i += 1;
    END
    RETURN @result;
END
GO

DECLARE @sentence NVARCHAR(100) = N'i-thINK-this    soLUTION-works-LiKe-a charm';
PRINT dbo.Capitalize(@sentence);
-- I-Think-This Solution-Works-Like-A Charm
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be as simple as this:

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(500) = 'Roger';

SELECT @Name AS Name, UPPER(LEFT(@Name, 1)) + SUBSTRING(@Name, 2, LEN(@Name)) AS CapitalizedName;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest one-liner to do this:

```
SELECT LEFT(column, 1)+ lower(RIGHT(column, len(column)-1) ) FROM [tablename]
```

Comment: Note, each column should be trimmed of whitespace or this breaks.

Comment: Also, you are not doing Upper on the first letter.

Comment: This only capitalizes the first letter of the column

Comment: @Amrik As `@JohnnyBizzle` commented above, I think you meant the following: `select 
        UPPER(LEFT(column, 1)) + lower(RIGHT(column, len(column)-1) )
     from [tablename]`

Comment: Use `lower (stuff (column, 1,1, ''))`  instead of `lower(RIGHT(column, len(column)-1) )`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the best way to capitalize and i recreate simple sql script

how to use SELECT dbo.Capitalyze('this is a test   with multiple   spaces')

result "This Is A Test With Multiple Spaces"

```
CREATE FUNCTION Capitalyze(@input varchar(100) )
    returns varchar(100)
as
begin
    
    declare @index int=0
    declare @char as varchar(1)=' '
    declare @prevCharIsSpace as bit=1
    declare @Result as varchar(100)=''

    set @input=UPPER(LEFT(@input,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(@input, 2, LEN(@input)))
    set @index=PATINDEX('% _%',@input)
    if @index=0
        set @index=len(@input)
    set @Result=substring(@input,0,@index+1)

    WHILE (@index < len(@input))
    BEGIN
        SET @index = @index + 1
        SET @char=substring(@input,@index,1)
        if (@prevCharIsSpace=1)
        begin
            set @char=UPPER(@char)
            if (@char=' ')
                set @char=''
        end

        if (@char=' ')
            set @prevCharIsSpace=1
        else
            set @prevCharIsSpace=0

        set @Result=@Result+@char
        --print @Result
    END
    --print @Result
    return @Result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

On **SQL Server 2016+** using JSON which gives guaranteed order of the words:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[InitCap](@Text NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN STUFF((
        SELECT ' ' + UPPER(LEFT(s.value,1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(s.value,2,LEN(s.value)))
        FROM OPENJSON('["' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(@Text,'\','\\'),'"','\"'),CHAR(9),'\t'),CHAR(10),'\n'),' ','","') + '"]') s
        ORDER BY s.[key]
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'');
END
```

Answer (score -1):

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('dbo.fnCapitalizeFirstLetterAndChangeDelimiter') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.fnCapitalizeFirstLetterAndChangeDelimiter
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnCapitalizeFirstLetterAndChangeDelimiter] (@string NVARCHAR(MAX), @delimiter NCHAR(1), @new_delimeter NCHAR(1))
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT @result = '';
    IF (LEN(@string) > 0)
        DECLARE @curr INT
        DECLARE @next INT
        BEGIN
            SELECT @curr = 1
            SELECT @next = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string)
            WHILE (LEN(@string) > 0)
                BEGIN
                    SELECT @result = 
                        @result + 
                        CASE WHEN LEN(@result) > 0 THEN @new_delimeter ELSE '' END +
                        UPPER(SUBSTRING(@string, @curr, 1)) + 
                        CASE 
                            WHEN @next <> 0 
                            THEN LOWER(SUBSTRING(@string, @curr+1, @next-2))
                            ELSE LOWER(SUBSTRING(@string, @curr+1, LEN(@string)-@curr))
                        END
                    IF (@next > 0)
                        BEGIN
                            SELECT @string = SUBSTRING(@string, @next+1, LEN(@string)-@next)
                            SELECT @next = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string)
                        END
                    ELSE
                        SELECT @string = ''
                END
        END
    RETURN @result
END
GO
```

Comment: Hello Andrew. Please provide a description of your solution and try to [use markdown to improve your answer readability](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) to format your code.