# SQL: capitalize first letter only

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need an SQL statement to capitalize the first letter of each word. The other characters have to be lower case.

The words can be like this:

```
wezembeek-oppem
roeselare
BRUGGE
louvain-la-neuve
```

Which would have to be:

```
Wezembeek-Oppem
Roeselare
Brugge
Louvain-La-Neuve
```

This should be with an UPDATE statement, I want to update the data of a column.
Thank you very much for your answers in advance, I'm an SQL novice.

Comment: In case the words are seperated by a space:
`SELECT INITCAP(full_name) FROM names`

Comment: To be honest, I consider this to be an XY-problem. The problem lies here: "The words can be like this:", followed by a list of inappropriate entries. My solution would be, to 1) fix all entries in the table so that they contain the appropriate casing (using an ad hoc or even a manual update approach) and 2) make some mechanism to guard for invalid entries. That way, there would be no need for such obscure SQL statements, which also slow down the performance. But that's just my own humble opinion, of course...

Answer (score 275, accepted):

Are you asking for renaming column itself or capitalise the data inside column? If its data you've to change, then use this:

```
UPDATE [yourtable]
SET word=UPPER(LEFT(word,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(word,2,LEN(word)))
```

If you just wanted to change it only for displaying and do not need the actual data in table to change:

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(word,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(word,2,LEN(word))) FROM [yourtable]
```

**EDIT: I realised about the '-' so here is my attempt to solve this problem in a function.**

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CapitalizeFirstLetter]
(
--string need to format
@string VARCHAR(200)--increase the variable size depending on your needs.
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
AS

BEGIN
--Declare Variables
DECLARE @Index INT,
@ResultString VARCHAR(200)--result string size should equal to the @string variable size
--Initialize the variables
SET @Index = 1
SET @ResultString = ''
--Run the Loop until END of the string

WHILE (@Index <LEN(@string)+1)
BEGIN
IF (@Index = 1)--first letter of the string
BEGIN
--make the first letter capital
SET @ResultString =
@ResultString + UPPER(SUBSTRING(@string, @Index, 1))
SET @Index = @Index+ 1--increase the index
END

-- IF the previous character is space or '-' or next character is '-'

ELSE IF ((SUBSTRING(@string, @Index-1, 1) =' 'or SUBSTRING(@string, @Index-1, 1) ='-' or SUBSTRING(@string, @Index+1, 1) ='-') and @Index+1 <> LEN(@string))
BEGIN
--make the letter capital
SET
@ResultString = @ResultString + UPPER(SUBSTRING(@string,@Index, 1))
SET
@Index = @Index +1--increase the index
END
ELSE-- all others
BEGIN
-- make the letter simple
SET
@ResultString = @ResultString + LOWER(SUBSTRING(@string,@Index, 1))
SET
@Index = @Index +1--incerase the index
END
END--END of the loop

IF (@@ERROR
<> 0)-- any error occur return the sEND string
BEGIN
SET
@ResultString = @string
END
-- IF no error found return the new string
RETURN @ResultString
END
```

So then the code would be:

```
UPDATE [yourtable]
SET word=dbo.CapitalizeFirstLetter([STRING TO GO HERE])
```

Comment: This won't handle the hyphenated cases.

Comment: yes, it would be an update of an existing column, I added this to my initial question.

Comment: added an attempted answer to deal with hyphenated cases - not tested as I am at work so its a quick attempt, might need tweaking.

Comment: I actually found my solution here; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054/whats-the-best-way-to-capitalise-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-in-s but your solution is very similar. Thanks!

Comment: I tried your function, for me it also uppercased the letter before the hyphen.

Comment: Mysql didn't support the concatenation using +, Anyone using Mysql might want to try CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(word,1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(word,2,LEN(word))))

Comment: For me, it works like this : `SELECT CONCAT( UPPER(LEFT(word,1)) , LOWER(SUBSTRING(word, 2, LENGTH(word))) ) as Word FROM [yourtable]`

Answer (score 16):

Create the below function

```
Alter FUNCTION InitialCap(@String VARCHAR(8000))
                  RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
                 AS
 BEGIN 

                   DECLARE @Position INT;

SELECT @String   = STUFF(LOWER(@String),1,1,UPPER(LEFT(@String,1))) COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin,
                    @Position = PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z''][a-z]%',@String COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin);

                    WHILE @Position > 0
                    SELECT @String   = STUFF(@String,@Position,2,UPPER(SUBSTRING(@String,@Position,2))) COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin,
                    @Position = PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z''][a-z]%',@String COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin);

                     RETURN @String;
  END ;
```

Then call it like

```
select dbo.InitialCap(columnname) from yourtable
```

Comment: You should [attribute your code sources](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost993409.aspx).

Comment: This Jef's Moden function doesn't work with names with accents.

Answer (score 5):

Please check the query without using a function:

```
declare @T table(Insurance varchar(max))

insert into @T values ('wezembeek-oppem')
insert into @T values ('roeselare')
insert into @T values ('BRUGGE')
insert into @T values ('louvain-la-neuve')

select (
       select upper(T.N.value('.', 'char(1)'))+
                lower(stuff(T.N.value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, ''))+(CASE WHEN RIGHT(T.N.value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1)='-' THEN '' ELSE ' ' END)
       from X.InsXML.nodes('/N') as T(N)
       for xml path(''), type
       ).value('.', 'varchar(max)') as Insurance
from 
  (
  select cast('<N>'+replace(
            replace(
                Insurance, 
                ' ', '</N><N>'),
            '-', '-</N><N>')+'</N>' as xml) as InsXML
  from @T
  ) as X
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select replace(wm_concat(new),',','-') exp_res from (select distinct initcap(substr(name,decode(level,1,1,instr(name,'-',1,level-1)+1),decode(level,(length(name)-length(replace(name,'-','')))+1,9999,instr(name,'-',1,level)-1-decode(level,1,0,instr(name,'-',1,level-1))))) new from table;
connect by level<= (select (length(name)-length(replace(name,'-','')))+1 from table));
```

Comment: Not a SQL Server answer ...

Comment: ya i haven't seen the db specified !! my mistake....

The query is supposed to be for Oracle db..