# How can I change the first character of word to lowercase if it is between A and Z?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a very large table of words that are stored in a column called "English".

Is there a way that I could update the rows in this table such that any word that starts with an uppercase character A-Z is changed to the same character but lowercase.

Comment: the first letter only? or all the characters to be moved to lowercase?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: capitalize first letter only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290754/sql-capitalize-first-letter-only)

Comment: Please read [ask] and share what you have tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try following.

```
UPDATE  StudentMasters 
SET     StdName = LOWER(LEFT(StdName,1)) + SUBSTRING(StdName,2,LEN(StdName)) 
WHERE   LEFT(StdName,1) =  UPPER(LEFT(StdName,1)) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI
```

In this we have table name 'StudentMasters' and field name 'StdName'. above query will update your field value as per your expectation.

Answer (score 1):

try this with other sample data,

```
declare @t table(col1 varchar(50))
insert into @t values ('DF454fdgd'),('45345dfgfgdf')

SELECT *
    ,replace(col1, SUBSTRING(col1, 1, 2)
, LOWER(SUBSTRING(col1, 1, 2))) newCol
FROM @t
WHERE col1 LIKE '[A-Z]%'
```

Answer (score 0):

For making the first letter of the column to lowercase ,use the below script.

```
UPDATE y
SET YourColumn=LOWER(LEFT(YourColumn,1))+SUBSTRING(YourColumn,2,LEN(YourColumn))
FROM YourTable y
```

Comment: There must be WHERE condition as he wants word that starts with an uppercase character only.