# Capitalize first letter of each word in select statement SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have database values like the, and maybe more different structures

```
NAME1
NAME1 NAME2
NAME1-NAME2
NAME1 NAME2-NAME3
NAME1-NAME2 NAME3
```

I want my select query to return the names in the following structure:

```
Name1
Name1 Name2
Name1-Name2
Name1 Name2-Name3
Name1-Name2 Name3
```

I found a function that should do this ([Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054/)), but I get the following error message:

```
Msg 262, Level 14, State 18, Procedure InitCap, Line 1
CREATE FUNCTION permission denied in database 'C30_SZV-PRIS'.
```

I don't know a lot about functions but this seems like I need certain permissions that I don't have. I don't have a lot of permissions and I unfortunately won't be able to get them.

Therefore I'm looking for another way to solve this problem, maybe inside the select statement?

Comment: Another solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15290820/3270427

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/139382/capitalize-only-the-first-letter-of-each-word-of-each-sentence-in-sql-server

Comment: But this will only capitalize the first letter of the value, right? Not every word or words after hyphens, unless I use that `Function` but that doens't work as well.

Comment: @Zeina Any clue why, when I replace the value of `@a` to `@a=dbo.persons.persons_lastname` I'm getting the error `'The multi-part identifier could not be bound'`?

Comment: You can't fill many values in a single variable

Comment: How would I use the answer of your link on a database column of 9000 records?

Comment: i think,given link function is good enough to solve your problem.contact your DBA/or give your login id enough permission to create/alter function.

Comment: @KumarHarsh That's not an option. I asked my DBA but he wants to be 100% sure nobody alters the database.

Comment: @Grafit  You should be asking him to add in the function for you.  Not give you permission to add the function yourself.

Comment: you don't have to alter or create.tell your dba to run the script.Can you create proc ? then you not function ?what is the logic of your DBA ? ALTERNATE solution is to manipulate this in front end which is best solution.ask anybody.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. Replace the select statement in the cursor with your select statement. I know cursor's are demonic...I borrowed some of the code from @Espo that you linked to in your question.

```
/* declare variables */
DECLARE @origName       Varchar(255)
DECLARE @Index          INT
DECLARE @Char           CHAR(1)
DECLARE @PrevChar       CHAR(1)
DECLARE @InputString    Varchar(255)
DECLARE @OutputString   VARCHAR(255)

CREATE TABLE #names1 (
       id int IDENTITY(1,1)
      ,names varchar(255));

DECLARE name_cursor CURSOR FOR SELECT names FROM test1

OPEN name_cursor

FETCH NEXT FROM name_cursor INTO @origName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @InputString = @origName
    SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString)
SET @Index = 1

WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
    BEGIN
        SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
        SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                             ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
                        END

        IF @PrevChar IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', '(')
        BEGIN
            IF @PrevChar != '''' OR UPPER(@Char) != 'S'
                SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, @Index, 1, UPPER(@Char))
        END

        SET @Index = @Index + 1
    END

    INSERT INTO #names1
            (names)
    VALUES  (@OutputString)


    FETCH NEXT FROM name_cursor INTO @origName
END

CLOSE name_cursor
DEALLOCATE name_cursor

SELECT names FROM #names1

DROP TABLE #names1
```

Answer (score 0):

Based of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15291175/11967103) answer I wrote this function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.InitialCap(@String nvarchar(max)) RETURNS nvarchar(max) AS BEGIN

DECLARE @Position   int = 1;
SET     @String = ' ' + LOWER(@String);

WHILE   (@Position > 0)

SELECT  @String     = STUFF(@String, @Position, 2, UPPER(SUBSTRING(@String, @Position, 2))) COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin,
        @Position   = PATINDEX('%[^A-Za-z''][a-z]%', @String COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin)

;

RETURN STUFF(@String, 1, 1, '');

END

;
```