# Does an SQL has a Django's "get_FOO_display()" like analog?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, django

For example I have a field status in one of my models:

```
CHOICES = (
    ('new', u'New'),
    ('old', u'Old'),
)
status = models.CharField(u'Status', max_length=10, choices=CHOICES, default=0)
```

If I will type: `t1.status` in SQL I will get `new` & `old` instead of `New` & `Old`
whereas in django I can type: `get_status_display()` to get `New` & `Old`, how can I do that in SQL ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Django the [Choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#choices) tuple `('new', u'New')` is iterables of exactly two items.

The first element of tuple will be stored in database, It could be integer or just a character.

The second element is just a human-readable label and used when rendering the form widget and when retrieving the field representation.

SQL queries are directly executed on Database and there is no information of choices mapping kept in it, choices mapping is handled by Django ORM layer.

So you cannot get second element of tuple using SQL.

> If you want to just capitalize your output using SQL refer this
>   **[`post`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290754/sql-capitalize-first-letter-only)**