# Create trigger for first letter of first name and last name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want write a trigger which will change from lower case to upper case in the name and surname.In my table klient where  imie = name , and nazwisko = surname. How to do it in SQL Server?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[klient]
(
    [id_klient] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [id_silownia] [int] NOT NULL,
    [imie] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [nazwisko] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [telefon] [varchar](50) NULL,
)
```

Comment: This might help point you in the proper direction...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290754/sql-capitalize-first-letter-only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need something like this:

```
-- create the trigger, on table "klient", after insert
CREATE TRIGGER trg_uppercase
ON dbo.klient
AFTER INSERT 
AS 
BEGIN
    -- update the table dbo.Klient
    UPDATE k
    -- set "imie" to be first letter in UPPER(), rest as is
    SET imie = UPPER(SUBSTRING(i.imie, 1, 1)) + SUBSTRING(i.imie, 2, 999),
        nazwisko = UPPER(SUBSTRING(i.nazwisko, 1, 1)) + SUBSTRING(i.nazwisko, 2, 999)
    FROM dbo.klient k
    -- join with "pseudo-table" Inserted to update only what was freshly inserted
    INNER JOIN Inserted i ON k.id_klient = i.id_klient;
END
```

This still has some "rough edges" to iron out - e.g. what if your name is longer than 999 characters? How will it handle `NULL` values being inserted?

But it should be a decent starting point to get a feeling for how to write triggers and what you can do with them.