# Normalize capitalised string but keep what's in brackets the same

Tags: sql-server, function, stored-procedures

I have this bit of text that I wish to ProperCase a string in the database but I have a issue I am using the ProperCase stored procedure.

To fix the below issue I would need my function to repair what's in the brackets with a ToUpper some how. I'm using SQL Server 2017.

I have tried something like the following. But the issue Is I have data like the following

I would like my procudure to be in a function that i can reuse. This also needs to work in 2016

```
TEST DATA (BA1) 
TEST DATA 2 (BA2) 
TEST DATA 3 (BA3)
```

It should return

```
Test Data (BA1) 
Test Data 2 (BA2) 
Test Data 3 (BA3)
```

But instead it's returning:

```
Test Data (Ba1) 
Test Data 2 (Ba2) 
Test Data 3 (Ba3)
```

Any ideas how one would stop it going lower case? So in that I mean what is inside the ( left brack and right bracket should remain upper case or be turned into uper case)

The issue comes when it gets to the brackets (it's making the A lower case as well). I want my function to ignore the text inside the brackets.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.ProperCase') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION dbo.ProperCase
GO

CREATE FUNCTION dbo.PROPERCASE 
     (@str VARCHAR(8000))
RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
    SET @str = ' ' + @str
    SET @str = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( @str, ' a', ' A'), ' b', ' B'), ' c', ' C'), ' d', ' D'), ' e', ' E'), ' f', ' F'), ' g', ' G'), ' h', ' H'), ' i', ' I'), ' j', ' J'), ' k', ' K'), ' l', ' L'), ' m', ' M'), ' n', ' N'), ' o', ' O'), ' p', ' P'), ' q', ' Q'), ' r', ' R'), ' s', ' S'), ' t', ' T'), ' u', ' U'), ' v', ' V'), ' w', ' W'), ' x', ' X'), ' y', ' Y'), ' z', ' Z')
    RETURN RIGHT(@str, LEN(@str) - 1)
END
GO
```

**Edit 2**

I have also tried the following from the great answer here but same result

[SQL: capitalize first letter only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290754/sql-capitalize-first-letter-only)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CapitalizeFirstLetter]
(
--string need to format
@string VARCHAR(200)--increase the variable size depending on your needs.
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
AS

BEGIN
--Declare Variables
DECLARE @Index INT,
@ResultString VARCHAR(200)--result string size should equal to the @string variable size
--Initialize the variables
SET @Index = 1
SET @ResultString = ''
--Run the Loop until END of the string

WHILE (@Index <LEN(@string)+1)
BEGIN
IF (@Index = 1)--first letter of the string
BEGIN
--make the first letter capital
SET @ResultString =
@ResultString + UPPER(SUBSTRING(@string, @Index, 1))
SET @Index = @Index+ 1--increase the index
END

-- IF the previous character is space or '-' or next character is '-'

ELSE IF ((SUBSTRING(@string, @Index-1, 1) =' 'or SUBSTRING(@string, @Index-1, 1) ='-' or SUBSTRING(@string, @Index+1, 1) ='-') and @Index+1 <> LEN(@string))
BEGIN
--make the letter capital
SET
@ResultString = @ResultString + UPPER(SUBSTRING(@string,@Index, 1))
SET
@Index = @Index +1--increase the index
END
ELSE-- all others
BEGIN
-- make the letter simple
SET
@ResultString = @ResultString + LOWER(SUBSTRING(@string,@Index, 1))
SET
@Index = @Index +1--incerase the index
END
END--END of the loop

IF (@@ERROR
<> 0)-- any error occur return the sEND string
BEGIN
SET
@ResultString = @string
END
-- IF no error found return the new string
RETURN @ResultString
END
```

I have since tried to use the following however.

```
Create FUNCTION [dbo].[ProperCase2] 
     (@str VARCHAR(MAX))
     RETURNS VARCHAR(8000)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @keysValueToSearch NVARCHAR(4000) = '('
DECLARE @untilThisCharAppears NVARCHAR(4000) = ')'
DECLARE @keysValueToSearchPattern NVARCHAR(4000) = '%' + @keysValueToSearch + '%'
DECLARE @leftString NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @Length      INT

DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(4000)
DECLARE @lhb NVARCHAR(4000)
SET @lhb = SUBSTRING(
           @str,
           PATINDEX(@keysValueToSearchPattern, @str) + LEN(@keysValueToSearch),
           CHARINDEX(
               @untilThisCharAppears,
               @str,
               PATINDEX(@keysValueToSearchPattern, @str) + LEN(@keysValueToSearch)
           ) -(PATINDEX(@keysValueToSearchPattern, @str) + LEN(@keysValueToSearch))
       );

 SET @Length = CHARINDEX(@keysValueToSearch, @str)

set @leftString=  SUBSTRING(@str, 1, 
                 CASE WHEN @Length - 1 < 0 
                      THEN LEN(@str) 
                      ELSE @Length - 1 END)  
 RETURN  dbo.CapitalizeFirstLetter(@LeftString) + ' (' +@lhb + ')'
END
```

I get the following error

When I pass the following test data

```
SELECT dbo.ProperCase2('Test DBA (BA1)') AS Test1 
SELECT dbo.ProperCase2('Test DBA EA1') AS Test2
```

> (1 row affected) Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 4 Invalid length
> parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: I think you will need a `while` loop to cycle through the string, keeping track of the logic.

Comment: @GordonLinoff please see my edit above I have also tried that using another function but to no avail it still makes the brackets lower case

Comment: I use a CLR function for this as these type of complex string manipulations are much easier in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't an ideal solution, but it appears to work. I use a couple of inline table-value functions here. Scalar function don't tend to perform (anywhere) as well as inline table-value functions, and although 2019 supports scalar inlining you're using 2017.

Firstly, you'll need to grab a copy of [`DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2), as we need a splitter that supports ordinal position (which `STRING_SPLIT` does not). Then we can use some windowed `SUM`s to check the count of brackets. If we're in the positive, then we're inside brackets and should not be apply the "proper" casing. I also *assumed* that there could be data *after* the parenthesis, as otherwise this is actually easier: This gives the below:

```sql
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION dbo.ProperCase (@String varchar(8000))
RETURNS table
AS RETURN
    WITH Split AS(
        SELECT DS.ItemNumber,
               DS.Item,
               SUM(CASE CHARINDEX('(',DS.Item) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) - 
               ISNULL(SUM(CASE CHARINDEX(')',DS.Item) WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) OVER (ORDER BY DS.ItemNumber ASC ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),0) AS InBrackets
        FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(@String,' ') DS)
    SELECT STRING_AGG(CASE S.InBrackets WHEN 0 THEN STUFF(LOWER(S.Item),1,1,UPPER(LEFT(S.Item,1))) ELSE S.Item END,' ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY S.ItemNumber) AS NewString
    FROM Split S;
GO

SELECT *
FROM (VALUES('TEST DATA (BA1)'),
            ('TEST DATA 2 (BA2)'),
            ('TEST DATA 3 (BA3)'),
            ('TEST DATA 4 (BA4) TEST'))V(YourString)
     CROSS APPLY dbo.ProperCase(V.YourString);

GO
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=7f8e17fcc9fa733c4d1b2cc98b52fe87)

Comment: Does it work when their is no left or right bracket as I am getting an error when their is not

Comment: What error are you getting? It doesn't produce one for me.

Comment: Why are u using FROM dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD im not in any of my functions

Comment: ... From the answer @rogue39nin *"Firstly, you'll need to grab a copy of `DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD`, as we need a splitter that supports ordinal position (which `STRING_SPLIT` does not)"*.

Comment: I made an updated [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c583c050005bba7b175bb1c6f6fad2e4) as well, and I do not get an error when the value does not contain any parenthesis, @rogue39nin .

Comment: Where did u get DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD it doesnt look like something you created yourself

Comment: ... Again, that is it in the answer, @rogue39nin . Click the hyperlink. That takes you to an article all about the function; including its definition.

Comment: I cant seem to run this as part of a select eg select dbo.ProperCase?

Comment: It's an inline table value function, @rogue39nin, not a scalar function *" I use a couple of inline table-value functions here. Scalar function don't tend to perform (anywhere) as well as inline table-value functions, and although 2019 supports scalar inlining you're using 2017."* Please do take the time to read the text prior to the solution, as I take the time there to explain the solution there.

Comment: Its just i need to be able to run it as part of a update clause

Comment: Which you can do, @rogue39nin ... `UPDATE {Alias} SET {Column} = PC.NewString FROM {Table} {alias} CROSS APPLY dbo.ProperCase ({alias}.{Column}) PC;`... it's no different I show you how to reference the function in the above answer

Comment: Yeah UPDATE dbo.Test SET Description = PC.NewString FROM dbo.Test CROSS APPLY dbo.ProperCase (Description) PC

Comment: If this *did* solve the problem, please do consider marking it as the solution, so that future readers know it was helpful, @rogue39nin . Many thanks. If it didn't, please do explain why and I';ll see what needs changing (though you will likely need to edit your question with the new criteria).

Comment: this is not working in version 13.05 in sql server 2016 would you no how to solve this. because STRING_AGG does not exist in it

Comment: You would need to use the older `FOR XML PATH` method, @rogue39nin ; as you stated you were using SQL server 2017, I specifically made a solution that worked in SQL Server 2017 (and onwards).

Comment: I taged sql-server not a specific versiontag

Comment: From your question, @rogue39nin : *"To fix the below issue I would need my function to repair what's in the brackets with a ToUpper some how. **I'm using SQL Server 2017.**"*

Comment: If you are now saying you are using SQL Server 2016 (not 2017) and fail to convert the above solution, you should post a new questing, citing this question, and explaining you are trying to convert the query to work on 2016, and failed to use `FOR XML PATH`, @rogue39nin . Don't forget to show your attempt at the `FOR XML PATH` version as well. Changing your question would invalidate the answers here, which is severely frowned upon and such edits are normally rolled back by contributers.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you have only one set of parens and this is at the end, you could split the string, proper case the first part and glom back the second.  Something like this:

```
BEGIN
    SET @newstr = ' ' + LEFT(@str, CHARINDEX('(', @str);
    SET @newstr = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE( @str, ' a', ' A'), ' b', ' B'), ' c', ' C'), ' d', ' D'), ' e', ' E'), ' f', ' F'), ' g', ' G'), ' h', ' H'), ' i', ' I'), ' j', ' J'), ' k', ' K'), ' l', ' L'), ' m', ' M'), ' n', ' N'), ' o', ' O'), ' p', ' P'), ' q', ' Q'), ' r', ' R'), ' s', ' S'), ' t', ' T'), ' u', ' U'), ' v', ' V'), ' w', ' W'), ' x', ' X'), ' y', ' Y'), ' z', ' Z')
    RETURN STUFF(@newstr, 1, 1, '') + RIGHT(@str, CHARINDEX('(', REVERSE(@str))
END;
```

Note:  this is a very specific answer to hack your current function based on the input that you have stated.

In general, I would suggest that you rewrite the function to loop through the string, character by character, so you can keep track of multiple parenthetical expressions.

Comment: Please see my edit 2 its more the function I am wanting to use

Answer (score 0):

You can do it just using SQL, without any procedure.

```
WITH
-- your input
indata(s) AS (
          SELECT 'TEST DATA (BA1)'
UNION ALL SELECT 'TEST DATA 2 (BA2)'
UNION ALL SELECT 'TEST DATA 3 (BA3)'
)
,
-- add an identifier, which you need for grouping later ...
w_id AS (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s) AS id
  , *
  FROM indata
)
, 
-- "explode" into one row per space delimited sub-string using STRING_SPLIT() ...
words AS (
  SELECT 
   id
  ,value
  FROM w_id
  CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(s,' ')
)
,
-- check if the "value" you got begins with a left paren 
-- and ends with a right paren, and proceed accordingly ...
right_case AS (
  SELECT
    id
  , CASE WHEN LEFT(value,1) <> '(' AND RIGHT(value,1) <> ')'
      THEN UPPER(LEFT(value,1))+LOWER(RIGHT(value,LEN(value)-1))
      ELSE value
    END AS val
  FROM words
)
-- finally, re-aggregate all together ...
SELECT
  STRING_AGG(val,' ') AS s
FROM right_case
GROUP BY id;

s
Test Data (BA1)
Test Data 2 (BA2)
Test Data 3 (BA3)
```

Comment: Im using 2017 so would like it as a function that can reuse for other jobs

Comment: When a person asks about a procedure they usually want it as a proc or function not a normal sql statement

Comment: still means u should take into account my orginal functions

Comment: @rogue39nin Often one is able to convert SQL statement(s) into function on procedure ;)

Comment: l got an issue with sql version 13.05 saying that   STRING_AGG is not supported anything else I can use my production db version must be earlier than 2017