# How to capitalize the first letter of a record in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a Comments field and I want to capitalize the first letter of the string in each record eg change 'duplicate' into 'Duplicate'. Some records will already have a capital at the start, and some may even be a number.

I tried this

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(Comments,1))+SUBSTRING(Comments,2,LEN(Comments)) FROM dbo.Template_Survey
```

but it fails because my field is an 'ntext' type.

It would also be useful to be able to capitalize the first letter after a full stop (period) but this is not essential unless someone has the code already written.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your column datatype?

Comment: Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054/whats-the-best-way-to-capitalise-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-in-s

Comment: Datatype is ntext. I'll take a look at the link now thanks though I did scour this site for quite some time before posting the question.

Comment: That link capitalizes the first letter of every word, I only need the first letter of the string capitalized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cast your ntext to nvarchar(max) and do the upper and left operations. Sample below.

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(cast(Comments as nvarchar(max)),1)) +
LOWER(SUBSTRING(cast(Comments as nvarchar(max)),2,
LEN(cast(Comments as nvarchar(max)))))  
FROM dbo.Template_Survey;
```

Following should work for update.

```
Update dbo.Template_Survey SET Comments = 
UPPER(LEFT(cast(Comments as nvarchar(max)),1)) +
LOWER(SUBSTRING(cast(Comments as nvarchar(max)),2,
LEN(cast(Comments as nvarchar(max)))));
```

Comment: That works fine but my error, how do I turn that into an update query to permanently replace with the capitalized first letter.

Answer (score 2):

Cast you column to nvarchar(max)

here is the working example

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5dd26/3

To update records you can use:

```
Update dbo.Template_Survey
 set Comments = UPPER(LEFT(cast(Comments as nvarchar(max)),1)) +
LOWER(SUBSTRING(cast(Comments as nvarchar(max)),2,
LEN(cast(Comments as nvarchar(max)))))
```

Comment: That works fine but my error, how do I turn that into an update query to permanently replace with the capitalized first letter.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late on my post here, but this solution is shorter. This works in sql server 2008+:

```
SELECT
  UPPER(CAST(Comments as nchar(1)))+LOWER(STUFF(CAST(Comments as nvarchar(max)),1,1,''))
FROM dbo.Template_Survey
```

Answer (score 0):

or:

```
UPDATE `table` SET name = CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(name,1)),LOWER(RIGHT(name,LENGTH(name)-1)))
```