# Basic proper case string in generic SQL

Tags: sql

I'm looking for a very basic version of proper case usable across SQL languages. This would only uppercase the first letter, and lowercase the rest (per record, not per word). For example, if a record has the value of `x` "the sky is GRAY", it would become "The sky is gray".

Comment: Answered here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054/what-s-the-best-way-to-capitalise-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-in-s

Comment: @dfundako that's only for SQL server, and capitalizes the first letter of each word. I'm looking for something across SQL engines and that only capitalizes first letter of the full string.

Comment: You won't find a single statement that works across all DBMS for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CONCAT` and concatenate part of string.

```
CREATE TABLE tab(x VARCHAR(1000));

INSERT INTO tab VALUES ('the sky is GRAY');

SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(x, 1)), LOWER(RIGHT(x, LENGTH(x) - 1))) AS result
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28ee4/1/0)**</kbd>

For more secure solution I would also trim text, because:

```
INSERT INTO tab VALUES ( '   the sky is GRAY');
```

You will get:

```
    the sky is gray
```

With trim:

```
SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(TRIM(x), 1)), 
              LOWER(RIGHT(TRIM(x), LENGTH(TRIM(x)) - 1))) AS result
FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2cf40/2/0)**</kbd>

*Warning:*

I highly doubt there's one query to "rule them all." Depending on your RDBMS, you may need to use:

- `SUBSTRING` instead of `LEFT/RIGHT`
- `LTRIM(RTRIM)` instead of `TRIM`
- `LEN/DATALENGTH` instead of `LENGTH`
- `+/||` instead of `CONCAT`

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(x, 1)), LOWER(RIGHT(x, LENGTH(x) - 1)))`

Comment: Probably you wanted `SELECT CONCAT(UPPER(LEFT(x, 1)), LOWER(RIGHT(x, LENGTH(x) - 1)))` In your current form it won't work

Answer (score 1):

An answer in pure Standard SQL would be:

```
UPPER(SUBSTRING(x FROM 1 FOR 1)) || LOWER(SUBSTRING(x FROM 2))
```