# Capitalise first letter of each word without changing currently Capitalised letters

Tags: sql-server

I need to capitalise the first letter of each word but keep any capitals that may already be there in a textbox on submit to SQL Server. I currently have an SQL function that I call, but that Capitalises the first letter and lowercases the rest of each word.
For example what I need is,

john smith - John Smith 
ABC limited - ABC Limited

Below is the SQL function I currently have.

```
 ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CAP_FIRST] ( @InputString varchar(4000) ) 
 RETURNS VARCHAR(4000) AS BEGIN

 DECLARE @Index          INT DECLARE @Char           CHAR(1) DECLARE
 @PrevChar       CHAR(1) DECLARE @OutputString   VARCHAR(255)

 SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString) SET @Index = 1

 WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString) BEGIN
     SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
     SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                          ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
                     END

     IF @PrevChar IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', '(')
     BEGIN
         IF @PrevChar != '''' OR UPPER(@Char) != 'S'
             SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, @Index, 1, UPPER(@Char))
     END

     SET @Index = @Index + 1 END

 RETURN @OutputString

 END
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What’s the best way to capitalise the first letter of each word in a string in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054/what-s-the-best-way-to-capitalise-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-in-s)

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the database instead of the client? All languages and reporting tools have functions that can perform capitalization easily. SQL does *not*. It's not a string manipulation language

Comment: This is much easier to do in the application layer

Comment: For example - your method would only work for *some* English names only.  It's not an inline function which means it would cause performance problems as well. In C# though, it's just a call to [CultureInfo.ToTitleCase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.textinfo.totitlecase(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Ah okay, I will do it that way instead. Thank you for your help everyone.  @RafalZiolkowski that possible duplicate isn't exactly what i want. But thanks anyway.

Comment: @Emma I think you just need a one line change to the function, q.v. below.  As others said, you might want to handle this in your app layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that the following line is responsible for lowercasing the entire input string:

```
SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString)
```

Then, the function selectively upper cases what it perceives to be the start of each word.  Replace the above line with the following assignment and the original case of the input string should be preserved:

```
SET @OutputString = @InputString
```

Comment: That did the trick thank you, but i have decided to take the comments on board and do what I need through c#.

Comment: @Emma Sounds like a plan, but maybe this answer will be useful to someone who chooses to use the function.