# SQL - Capitalize every word ignoring capitals

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to be able to convert something like

```
'ABC abc abc Abc'
```

to

```
'ABC Abc Abc Abc'
```

So the first letter of every word becomes capital and words that have capitals remain the same.

I have tried `initcap` but this turns the rest of each word into lowercase after it has been capitalized.

```
select initcap('ABC abc abc Abc') from dual;
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What’s the best way to capitalise the first letter of each word in a string in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054/what-s-the-best-way-to-capitalise-the-first-letter-of-each-word-in-a-string-in-s)

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option:

```
SQL> with
  2  test as
  3    (select 'ABC abc abc Abc' col from dual),
  4  tor as
  5    -- convert COL into rows
  6    (select regexp_substr(col, '[^ ]+', 1, level) val
  7     from test
  8     connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ' ') + 1),
  9  capit as
 10    -- choose whether to capitalize first letter or not
 11    (select case when upper(val) = val then val
 12                 else initcap(val)
 13            end cap
 14     from tor)
 15  -- concatenate them back to a string
 16  select listagg(cap, ' ') within group (order by null) result
 17  from capit;

RESULT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC Abc Abc Abc

SQL>
```

Or, a little bit modified:

```
SQL> with
  2  test as
  3    (select 'ABC abc abc Abc' col from dual)
  4  select listagg(
  5         case when         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, level) =
  6                   upper(  regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, level))
  7              then         regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, level)
  8              else initcap(regexp_substr(col, '\w+', 1, level))
  9         end, ' ') within group (order by null) res
 10  from test
 11  connect by level <= regexp_count(col, ' ') + 1;

RES
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
ABC Abc Abc Abc

SQL>
```