# How to capitalize first letter of first name and surname from an email address?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am trying to pull out a name from an email address, which will always be in the format `firstname.lastname@domain`

I have done this using the following statement:

`replace(left(column, charindex('@', column) - 1), '.', ' '), 1)) AS Requestor`

However, some of the email's have names in lower case, and I also need to capitalize if that is the case. `joe bloggs` = `Joe Bloggs`

Is the best option to create a function that does this, or can someone suggest an update to the statement above to handle this?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What do *you* mean by "capitalize"?

Comment: Hint : `UPPER()`.

Comment: Maybe like this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/55057/3489104

Comment: @GordonLinoff first letter of first and last name to be capitalized

Comment: What about people with names that should have two upper case letters, such as McDonald?

Comment: @iamdave not interested in that for now. Just first letter for first and last name.

Comment: You say *for now*, which suggests it will be necessary further down the line?  This is a ridiculously difficult problem which I think you are underestimating.

Comment: @iamdave lets just say it wont be necessary further down the line, is it best to create a function, of which there are numerous examples, or can this be done in the select statement, of which I haven't yet found a suitable solution explaining the process so I can understand it.

Comment: To go along with @iamdave: Why not just have the names all in upper case? That makes the query easier, and avoids any issues with names like McDonald. Also, how certain are you that the email will __always__ be in the format `firstname.lastname@domain`? Maybe you should store the name in a separate field (which could default to the algorithm you use)...

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question as it stands this is fairly basic string manipulation, which as you will see from the verbosity of the code below, is not SQL Server's strong suit:

```
declare @e table (e varchar(100));
insert into @e values('tom.mcdonald@email.com'),('dan.oneill@email.com')

select e.e
      ,upper(left(f,1)) + substring(f,2,999) + ' ' + upper(left(s,1)) + substring(s,2,999) as n
from @e as e
    cross apply(values(substring(e.e,1,charindex('.',e.e)-1)
                      ,substring(e.e,charindex('.',e.e)+1,charindex('@',e.e,1)-charindex('.',e.e)-1)
                      )
               ) as n(f,s);
```

## Output

```
+------------------------+--------------+
|           e            |      n       |
+------------------------+--------------+
| tom.mcdonald@email.com | Tom Mcdonald |
| dan.oneill@email.com   | Dan Oneill   |
+------------------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can upper case the entire string using `upper()`:

```
upper(replace(left(column, charindex('@', column) - 1), '.', ' '), 1)))
```

You can upper case the first character  using `stuff()`:

```
stuff(replace(left(column, charindex('@', column) - 1), '.', ' '),
      1, 1, upper(left(column, 1))
     )
```

Comment: Error using above code `stuff requires 4 arguments`

Answer (score 0):

I would do :

```
select upper(left(fname, 1)) + right(fname, len(fname) - 1) + ' ' + upper(left(lname, 1)) + right(lname, len(lname) - 1) as Requestor
from table t cross apply
     ( values ( left(col, charindex('@', col) - 1) ) 
     ) t(nm) cross apply
     ( values ( left(nm, charindex('.', nm)-1), right(nm, charindex('.', reverse(nm))-1) ) 
     )  t1(fname, lname);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going through the trouble of extracting the names, and capitalising the first letter, then I would not mash them back together. Instead I would leave them as two columns so any further manipulation you do does not require more splitting.

You can leverage(*abuse*) the [`PARSENAME`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/parsename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to split a string based on `.` so you could use something like:

```
-- CAPITALISE FIRST LETTER WITH STUFF AND UPPER
SELECT  Forename = STUFF(t2.Forename, 1, 1, UPPER(LEFT(t2.Forename, 1))),
        Surname = STUFF(t2.Surname, 1, 1, UPPER(LEFT(t2.Surname, 1)))
FROM    (VALUES ('joe.blogs@domain.com')) x ([Column])
-- EXTRACT CHARACTERS TO THE LEFT OF THE @ SIGN
CROSS APPLY (SELECT LEFT([Column], CHARINDEX('@', [Column]) - 1)) AS t1 (FullName)
-- EXTRACT FIRST AND LAST NAME USING PARSENAME
CROSS APPLY (SELECT PARSENAME(FullName, 2), PARSENAME(FullName, 1)) AS t2 (Forename, Surname)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
declare @t table (email varchar(50))

insert into @t values ('xyz.xyz@gmail.com')

select upper(SUBSTRING(email,1,1)) + SUBSTRING(email,2,CHARINDEX('.',email)-1)+upper(SUBSTRING(email,CHARINDEX('.',email)+1,1)) + SUBSTRING(email,CHARINDEX('.',email)+2,len(email))   from @t
```