# Capitalize the first letter of each word without affecting the consecutive letters

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I would like to make the first letter of each word capitalized. However, if the word next to the first letter is already capitalized, then it should not be affected.

For example:

```
text
AB test
ab test
Ab tEst
```

Desired output:

```
text
AB Test
Ab Test
Ab TEst
```

When I tried with this query, even though it capitalized the first word, it also lowered the word next to it. For example, the below query goes from `ABC test` to `Abc Test`, and I would like to it to be `ABC Test`

```
SELECT INITCAP(text)
FROM table
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This may help..

Create a function and use it in select.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.InitialCap(@v AS VARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN 
WITH a AS (
    SELECT (
        SELECT UPPER(LEFT(value, 1)) + (SUBSTRING(value, 2, LEN(value))) AS 'data()'
        FROM string_split(@v, ' ')
        ORDER BY CHARINDEX(value,@v)
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE) ret)

SELECT CAST(a.ret AS varchar(MAX)) ret from a
```

reference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/46344989/8077687

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a [redshift function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_INITCAP.html) that already does this:

```
INITCAP(string)
```

**Example:**

```
INITCAP('ab test')
```

will return:

```
Ab test
```